Am I thinking about Clairaut's theorem correctly? Mixed Partial Derivatives
Clairaut's Theorem, states that if a function has continuous second partial derivatives, then the order in which you take the mixed partial derivatives does not matter.
I am quite new to this so I did not understand the proof with double integrals and a lot of other online post.
This is is how I explained this to myself (my notes basically)

Imagine a tissue paper that represents the graph of the function $f(x,y)=xy.$ In this context, $f(x,y)=xy$ describes a surface in 3D space. For any given point on this tissue, the height represents the value of $f(x,y).$

$$
f(x, y) = xy
$$
pull up desmos and graph
$$
xy =z
$$
and then
$$
2xy=z
$$
$$
3xy=z
$$

The first partial derivatives can be thought of as the slopes of the tissue paper in the $x$ and $y$ directions, respectively. Look at the surface from the side.

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} =x
$$
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} =y
$$
These derivatives tell us how the height of the tissue changes as we move in the $x$ or $y$ direction.

The second mixed partial derivatives ∂x∂y∂2f and ∂y∂x∂2f represent the curvature of the tissue paper, The rate of change of the different rates of change we found earlier.

The different partial derivatives do not have to be the same, but for this example they are.

Pulling on the Tissue Paper (Parameter t):

Now, imagine a parameter $“t”$ that represents a transformation or deformation of this tissue paper. If you pull one corner of the tissue paper up by a factor of 2, you are effectively transforming the function.


Effect on Derivatives:

When you pull up the tissue paper by a factor of 2 (i.e., multiplying $f(x,y)$ by 2), the first partial derivatives also double:

$$
f(x, y) = 2xy \\\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(2xy) = 2y, \quad \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(2xy) = 2x
$$

The second partial derivatives will also be affected proportionally, meaning if you were to compute the mixed partial derivatives, they would also scale by the same factor.



This effect works for any function, as long as the surface does not break (it is continuous). Sorry if calling the function $f(x,y)=xy*t$(parameter) a tissue paper was bit weird.
So is the reasoning valid here?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I don't understand why you need the $2$ and $3$.  For any function $f(x,y)$ with an elementary closed form, it's easy to compute $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ and $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y} \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and see that they are indeed equal.  The hard part is to prove that it's true in general.

Yes that is true, at first I did not even understand what this even meant. Those examples just helped me realize how elevating the corner effected both sides of the surface(The partial derivatives). But I really am thinking about how I might prove it.

Maybe you're looking for something like this.  For $f(x,y) = x^m y^n$ you have
$$ \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y} \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} = m n x^{m-1} y^{n-1}$$
Because of linearity
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (a f(x,y) + b g(x,y)) = a \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,y) + b \frac{\partial}{\partial x} g(x,y) $$
and similarly for $\partial/\partial y$, you get $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y} \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} $ for polynomials in $x$ and $y$. Taking limits, you can extend this to analytic functions, i.e. those represented by convergent power series in $x$ and $y$.
That covers nearly all cases you encounter in "real life", and would be enough for any 18th century mathematician. You only need  serious analysis to generalize the result to all functions where these partial derivatives exist and are continuous.
